# how can i use angular js into google charts

Tags: angularjs, charts, bar-chart

I want to customize the bar chart with the user's data, and redraw it accordingly on run time. user should give details on both axis and their values.
What code i should write to it ? Can angular variables be a good choice for doing it ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  600,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
      ['2008',  2000,      250]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('div1'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [AngularJs Google Chart Tools directive](http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/#/fat)

If you want to do things the "Angular way" you should use [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for all of your DOM manipulation. So i suggest you to store all of your data inside a controller, and then in your view use a directive to render a view from your data

Answer (score 1):

Go through this [Google chart tools AngularJs Directive](http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/#/fat)